# Laravel image intervention takes too long when watermarking

Tags: laravel, image, watermark, intervention

I have the following function in my Laravel project. It uses Intervention to watermark every picture after upload. Problem is it takes sooooo long to do it, over a minute, no matter it is just one picture.

Any ideas or alternatives?

```
function insertWatermark($value){
    $img = Image::make(public_path($value));

    $watermark = Image::make(public_path('watermark.png'))->opacity(50);

    $img->insert($watermark, 'center');

    $img->save(public_path($value));

    return $value;
}
```

Comment: i suggest you use Laravel events and queues and do that logic separately on a ShouldQueue class

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues

Comment: Thanks, it's something I didn't know. Will give it a try.

Comment: sure thing, happu coding

Comment: Let's see if I got it right... I've created a WatermarkPicture job with the above function code in handle() and called it after uploading the images with:  
  
    `WatermarkPicture::dispatch($path);`  
  
Processing still takes too long, in fact it ends with a 'Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded' message.  
  
I also understood a job record in the jobs table should be created but it isn't.